# Matlab trouble with a lot of data. Vibration data is 3 million rows long

Tags: matlab, performance

I have vibration data(g) in x and y direction for a Ball Bearing in 2 columns. Is there a way to find Manhattan distance just with this data & time?

Comment: Can you clarify which points you want to measure Manhattan distance between?

Comment: How is this a MATLAB question? It is a question about algorithms... Please show some sample data, some desired outputs, some attempts of your own... What are you having a problem with? Out of memory? Syntax? Do you have access to the newest versions of MATLAB? The question is very broad and the only answer that sufficiently covers it is **probably yes**.

Comment: Please make your title contain at least *some* information related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If all you look for is summing `data(:,1)` and `data(:,2)`, (as in [@Austin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39313893/2627163)) using vectored sum will be the fastest:

```
out = data(:,1)+data(:,2);
```

Here is an example:

```
function timming_mat_dist
data = randi(100,1e6,2);
timeit(@()arrmat(data))
timeit(@()vecmat(data))
end

function out = arrmat(data)
man_hat_dist_func = @(x,y)x+y;
out = arrayfun(man_hat_dist_func,data(:,1),data(:,2));
end

function out = vecmat(data)
out = data(:,1)+data(:,2);
end
```

and the results are **2.8936** seconds for `arrmat` and **0.0020463** seconds for `vecmat`.

---

However, if you want to compute all distances you should use [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html?searchHighlight=pdist):

```
out = pdist(data,'cityblock');
```

but be aware that the output will be huge (and MATLAB probably won't let allocate so much memory for that) as @hammadian pointed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39313931/2627163).

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarks. I didn't know about `pdist()`. If the math gets too complex, array fun may be useful, but I think your solution is best. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find manhattan distance for each set of x and y, I would recommend using `arrayfun`

The usage is as follows:

```
man_hat_dist_func = @(x,y)x+y;
out = arrayfun(man_hat_dist_func,data(:,1),data(:,2));
```

OR

```
out = arrayfun(@(x,y)x+y,data(:,1),data(:,2));
```

This should be your fastest option to solve the distances. You should also consider pre-allocating memory for `out` using `out = zeros(Length(data(:,1)),1);`.

Comment: `arrayfun` is not such a good option for such large data. A simple `for` loop will be quicker.

Comment: They should compile to about the same speed. I find arrayfun more robust.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which pair you want to measure the distance between. If you are looking for all possible combination of points, this will be memory and time consuming as the space requirement will be stored in 2D matrix of size:3 million * 3 million /2 ( /2 as distance between a and b is the same as b and a), so the matrix is upper triangular.
This is 3000000*3000000/2=4.5 Tera bytes. This can be improved but still will be very high in memory requirements.